# Notepad++ - Find 2 lines one line below the other

Tags: notepad++

I need to find in a Notepad++ text file over 200000 lines this combination:

```
8B 12                 - mov edx,[edx]
01 10                 - add [eax],edx
```

I need to find:

```
8B 12                 - mov edx,[edx]
```

and the next line must be:

```
01 10                 - add [eax],edx
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

You can include a newline character in your search,
this allows you to search for two lines.

Open find (ctrl+f) and enable extended mode:

[image]

Now search for either

```
8B 12                 - mov edx,[edx]\r\n01 10                 - add [eax],edx
```

Or

```
8B 12                 - mov edx,[edx]\n01 10                 - add [eax],edx
```

One of the two should match depending on what type of newline character your file uses.

\r\n (CR LF)= the default on Windows

\n (LF) = the default on Linux and Mac

There is also \r (CR) it's really uncommon nowadays but that would be:

```
8B 12                 - mov edx,[edx]\r01 10                 - add [eax],edx
```